# Integration of this type?

Tags: integration

Can anyone help me with this? I used completing the square but do not know how to continue? Thanks

> 9.. Gaussian Integral
>
> The following definite integration is particularly relevant in the
>   subject of quantum mechanics (QM). (It always pops out, so it is
>   worthwhile to memorise this when you are doing QM)
>
> $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ax^2} ~ dx = \left ( \frac{\pi}{a} \right )^{1/2}$$
>
> Find
>
> $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-4x^2 + 3x} ~ dx$$
>
> Hint: Complete the square for the exponent, i.e. write $4x^2 - 3x = \left ( 2x - \frac{3}{4} \right )^2 - \left ( \frac{3}{4} \right )^2$.

Answer (score 10):

1) Write it as: $$e^{\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{2}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\left(2x-\frac{3}{4}\right)^{2}}dx$$

2) Apply substitution $u=2x-\frac{3}{4}$